# How do i remove a chunk of text from a variable? (PHP)

Tags: php

I need to be able to remove a URL from a variable, I'm wondering how i do this. 
Example - Say my script returns http://www.example.com/file.php?id=1234 i need to be able to remove the http://www.example.com/file.php?id= bit, just leaving the id number. If anyone can help, it would be great :)

Comment: I know i could use $_GET to get url data, but im not getting it from the scripts URL. What im trying to edit is a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$var = 'http://www.example.com/file.php?id=1234';
$query = parse_url($var, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$query_components = parse_str($query);

$id = $query_components['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
preg_match("/id=(\\d+)/", $url, $matches);
$id = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Will this only output the id number?

Comment: Yes, look at @Marc B's answer...it's better. :-P

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$id = $_GET['id'];`.

See [the docs](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

And don't forget to validate and sanitize.

Answer (score 0):

The "id" in this case is being sent to your script as a GET variable, therefore you would access it as follows:

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
```

If you mean to say that this URL is not yours to control, then you would do this instead:

```
    print_r(parse_url($url)); // Then analyze the output.
```